# Objective Function of Maximum Margin Classifier(MMC) is Convex. How?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning, computational-mathematics, pattern-recognition

My Question is although a straight forward one but I've searched through google, stackexhange,forums etc. but unable to find the answer. Almost everywhere it's been assumed that objective function of MMC is Convex or it says "Read these notes on Convex Optimization" but i'm unable to find the exact answer to my problem.

So here it is, **How one can prove that Objective Function of Maximum Margin Classifier with constraint (as shown below in image) is Convex?**. **Do we also need to prove that constraint is convex too. If yes then How?** Any thorough explanation will be highly appreciated.

Looking forward for your help.Thanks!
[image]

Comment: You can compute the Hessian of the objective function and you will see that the Hessian is positive semidefinite, which shows that the objective function is convex. The constraints are linear inequality constraints, so they are convex. Boyd and Vandenberghe is a good textbook for learning to recognize convex optimization problems, and it has a section on maximum margin classifiers also. The book is free online.

Comment: But how to compute Hessian matrix of ||w||^2 ? Can you please answer it in detail. I shall be very thankful

Comment: As a warmup problem, let's compute the Hessian of the function $f(x) = \frac12 \| x \|_2^2 = \frac12 x_1^2 + \cdots + \frac12 x_n^2$.  (Here $x = (x_1,\ldots, x_n)$.) First of all, notice that $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i} = x_i$.  It follows that $\frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$ is equal to $0$ if $i \neq j$ and $1$ if $i = j$.  Thus, the Hessian $\nabla^2 f(x)$ is the identity matrix.  A similar computation will allow us to compute the Hessian for your objective function.

Comment: Thanks a million @littleO :)